# Problem with table width

Tags: tables, width

I have problem with table, it's always have same width.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtabu} to 5cm {|X|X|}
\caption{Информация об элементах структуры проекта ПУД}
\label{tab:04-01}
\\ \hline
Элемент структуры & Описание \\
\hline \endfirsthead
\subcaption{Продолжение таблицы~\ref{tab:04-01}}
\\ \hline \endhead

\endfoot
\hline \endlastfoot
.idea & Файлы среды разработки \\
\hline
config & Файлы конфигурации \\
\hline
db & Резервные копии БД \\
\hline
modules & Модули CMS \\
\hline
node\_modules & Сторонние библиотеки \\
```

[image]

here is what I want

[image]

Comment: please extend your code sniped to complete but small document with your table. it should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. table has width as you prescribed (5 cm) with equal width of columns (`|X|X|`). what is the problem? please, clarify.

Comment: Yes, width of columns is 5cm, but full width of table is fit page.

Comment: please edit the example so it produces the result shown, however probably the caption is forcing the table to be too wide. Note also that a longtable/longtabu should not be in a `center` environment.

Answer (score 1):

you should read documentation of the package. there this is clear described :-). try the following:

```
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X[1,l]|X[4,l]|} % \linewidth is width of text on the page
                                                 % 1 and 4 are ratio between columns widths
                                                 % l is option for left aligning of cells text
```

one example of such table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X[1,l]|X[4,l]|}
\caption{table caption}
\label{tab:04-01}                   \\
    \hline
short text  & longer text           \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{table caption (cont.)}     \\
    \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{continue on the next page}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
idea    &   \lipsum*[11]    \\
    \hline
idea    &   \lipsum*[11]    \\
    \hline
idea    &   \lipsum*[11]    \\
    \hline
idea    &   \lipsum*[11]    \\
    \hline
idea    &   \lipsum*[11]    \\
    \hline
idea    &   \lipsum*[11]    \\
    \hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

is this what you looking for?

**edit:**
if you like to have table width only 5cm, than in above document example (minimal working example: mwe) replace `\linewidth` with `5cm`. in this case you will obtain:

[image]

for further help you should more clear describe what is your problem. Note, your table in question has width 5cm!

Comment: I tried your command, but it's still not I want. I want my table width to be for example 5cm, but its always as page width.

Comment: you are not consistent with demands. than change `\linewidth` to `5cm`. it is not clear, what is your problem.

Comment: I made such in my example, and i expected table width to be 5cm

Comment: I'm updated my question

Comment: now your question is even less clear.  please, consider all comments below question. your claims about table do not hold. your code example after completing it gives table with 5cm width.